# Event to refresh UserControl Display

Tags: c#, events

I have a `UserControl` and a class for updating/storing results in a database. I need to automatically refresh the `UserControlResultDislpay` upon storing data. I have created and event to trigger a refresh when an Update occurs. I have the following code:

Class `InstrumentTest`:

```
public delegate void UpdateResultDisplay(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event UpdateResultDisplay RefreshDisplay;
protected virtual void OnNewResult(EventArgs e)
{
    if (RefreshDisplay != null)
        RefreshDisplay(this, e);
}

public void UpdateResultDB(ResultDataJFTOT resultData)
{
    AnalysisListCommon myresult = PContext.GetInstance().DbHandlerLocal.StoredResult(
        resultData.SampleId,
        resultData.TestDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        resultData.InstrumentSn,
        StringRepository.constStringSampleName);
    if (myresult != null)
    {
        Result r = new Result(new Guid(myresult.ResultId));
        ResultData rd = r.GetResultData("Rating", FindResultDataMode.byVariableIdentifier);
        string xmlTubeRating = resultData.tRating.ToString().Replace("#LT#", "<");
        rd.Text = xmlRating;
        rd.Store();
        rd = r.GetResultData("TestDate", FindResultDataMode.byVariableIdentifier);
        rd.Text = resultData.Date.ToString();
        rd.Store();
        OnNewResult(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
        AddTestToQueue(resultData);
    }
}

 public static InstrumentTest Instance()
{
    //If instance is null create a new instance of the InstrumentTest
    if (instrumentTestInstance == null)
    {
        instrumentTestInstance = new InstrumentTest();
    }
    return instrumentTestInstance;
}
```

Code from `UserControl`:

```
public UserControlResultDisplay()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.InitializeUIStrings();
    this.InitializePlot();
    EventListener(resultChanged);
}             

private InstrumentTest resultChanged = InstrumentTest.Instance();

public void EventListener(InstrumentTest resultChanged)
{
    //resultChanged = (InstrumentTest)obj;
    resultChanged.RefreshDisplay += DisplayNewResultData;                      
}

private void DisplayNewResultData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshCurrentResult();
}
```

Comment: Is the refresh not working? By looking at your code, it seems to be correct. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @Kiran Hegde The refresh just is'nt working. I have another form (childform of UserControlResultDisplay) that I call this refresh method from and it works beautifully. Its almost like my Listener is not working. I can debug to the point where the delegate/event  is called and then nothing.

Comment: When is UserControlResultDisplay function is called? OnLoad/OnInit? Try registering the event, by calling the listener code in OnInit function. 
resultChanged.RefreshDisplay += DisplayNewResultData;